# ORA-00905 Error in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The error is highlighting the issue as being in front of my WHERE clause of the main query. I am not sure as to what I am missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash (doi,seg,v) */
doi.ORDER_ID AS "PO"
, doi.DISTRIBUTOR_ID AS "Vendor ID"
, doi.ISBN AS "ASIN"
, doi.QUANTITY_ORDERED AS "Quantity Confirmed"
, v.VENDOR_NAME AS "Vendor"
FROM D_DISTRIBUTOR_ORDER_ITEMS doi
LEFT JOIN VENDORS v
JOIN    (SELECT /*+ use_hash */
    psm.ASIN
    FROM PRODUCT_SEGMENT_MEMBERSHIP psm
    WHERE psm.SEGMENT_ID = 784885) seg
ON doi.ISBN = seg.ASIN
AND doi.DISTRIBUTOR_ID = v.VENDOR_ID
WHERE doi.ORDER_DAY LIKE 2009/04/06
ORDER BY seg.ASINSIN
```

Comment: Do you really expect us to search the manual to find the complete message for `ORA-00905`?

Comment: Its a missing keyword error, my bad.

Comment: Yes, after "LEFT JOIN VENDORS v" you are missing the "on ..." verbiage.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick that looks like it will work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the join condition `doi.DISTRIBUTOR_ID = v.VENDOR_ID` from the where clause to the from clause and 
specifically after the `LEFT JOIN VENDORS v` as follows:

```
SELECT
  /*+ use_hash (doi,seg,v) */
  doi.order_id         AS "PO" ,
  doi.distributor_id   AS "Vendor ID" ,
  doi.isbn             AS "ASIN" ,
  doi.quantity_ordered AS "Quantity Confirmed" ,
  v.vendor_name        AS "Vendor"
FROM d_distributor_order_items doi
LEFT JOIN vendors v
ON doi.distributor_id = v.vendor_id
JOIN
  (SELECT
    /*+ use_hash */
    psm.asin
  FROM product_segment_membership psm
  WHERE psm.segment_id = 784885
  ) seg
ON doi.isbn                = seg.asin
WHERE trunc(doi.order_day) = '2009/04/06'
ORDER BY seg.asinsin
```

I embellished and assumed you wanted to trunc the date in lieu of using a like condition (does not make sense).

Comment: Any idea of where there could be a Parallel within that query?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`WHERE doi.ORDER_DAY LIKE 2009/04/06`

By

```
WHERE doi.ORDER_DAY LIKE '2009/04/06'
```

Comment: Well great catch, but sadly I am still getting the same error. in the same location. Thanks though @yassine__